# RSA and Wiener's attack

Tags: rsa, congruence

I'm trying to do Wieners' attack for the case \

```
n = 41812289888807017163984918063150535143241733968369526096686035411100281058895684734892837916893307091448099221185297849468517662339430579635277837641016589091836673752854703947923396020640786536145707 
c = 5647541533380963346585224364224434677403723951263986948810198754525250531609090519481526140311081703727277595838311994257275863156449937037100899820505224056792266899834932182748239916430052642900127.
```

I'm using SageMath and I computed the continued fraction of $n/c$ and the first 10 convergents ($p_n/q_n$). Now I'm trying to see if $a^{cq_i} \equiv a \pmod{n}$. It happens that Sage says that the exponent is too high and PARI online said the said. Can I make these computations an easier way?

Comment: If you have a problem with SageMath, there is https://ask.sagemath.org/questions/ for this type of question. Also, you can implement your binary modular exponentiation. Or, you can use GNU/MP.

Comment: The problem you have with the exponent being too high is caused by calculating first the exponent (resulting in a giant number) and then reducing modulo $n$. The reduction should be done during the exponentiation, not afterwards. In python you can use pow(b, e, m) for calculating $b^e\bmod m$.

Comment: @j.p. actually, I've tested with SageMath that can handle the very big exponenets, too. I don't see a reason. Better to be asked at ask.sagemath.org with the code.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about an error on SageMath and need to be asked at ask.sagamath.org

Answer (score 1):

"Too big" in modular exponentiation means that you're trying to exponentiate-*then*-modulo, which creates *huge* intermediate numbers; that isn't how you're supposed to do modular-root-based cryptography. You should use SageMath's [`IntegerModRing`](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/finite_rings/sage/rings/finite_rings/integer_mod_ring.html) to [work inside such groups](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/prep/Quickstarts/Number-Theory.html#modular-arithmetic), instead of "manually" running a modulo operation on attempted exponentiation results.

```
sage: R = IntegerModRing(n)
sage: a = R(a)
sage: assert a^(c*q[i])  == a
```

Dedicated modular-exponentiation systems will *internally* "cheat" by keeping numbers pruned to a manageable size throughout the process (generally with a technique like [Montgomery reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_modular_multiplication?oldid=1087121523#The_REDC_algorithm)) so they never have to handle "exponentially large" numbers.

---

Or, if you're just aiming at a "quick and dirty" calculation, you could use [`power_mod`](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/rings_standard/sage/arith/misc.html#sage.arith.misc.power_mod) (*cf.* Python's [`pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow), OpenSSL's [`BN_mod_mul`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/BN_mod_mul.html#:%7E:text=BN_mod_mul%28%29), *etc.*)